how i can use requests inside numba @jit
my code:
the code is try to send request to google
from numba import jit
import requests
@jit()
def x():
   requests.get("https://google.com")
x()

the error:
that is the text of error i got it
[Running] python -u "/home/nfrxd/Documents/kk.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nfrxd/Documents/kk.py", line 6, in <module>
    x()
  File "/home/nfrxd/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 468, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "/home/nfrxd/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
[1m[1mUnknown attribute 'get' of type Module(<module 'requests' from '/home/nfrxd/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/__init__.py'>)
[1m
File "kk.py", line 5:[0m
[1mdef x():
[1m   requests.get("https://google.com")
[0m   [1m^[0m[0m
[0m
[0m[1mDuring: typing of get attribute at /home/nfrxd/Documents/kk.py (5)[0m
[1m
File "kk.py", line 5:[0m
[1mdef x():
[1m   requests.get("https://google.com")
[0m   [1m^[0m[0m


[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.631 seconds

i tried use njit so any way to fix?

I don't think there would be any benefit to using requests inside of numba. I don't think numba can meaningfully accelerate a network request.

Just read the Numba doc. Many people do not read it and ask question about that here while there is an explanation of this in the first pages.

I'm assuming you understand that numba is designed to be used with NumPy arrays and functions (that is stated on their home-page).
Numba won't make your request to google.com faster, it is mainly used for speeding up numerical processing.
But if your example is only part of the code (that is using requests inside jitted function) you can use numba.objmode, e.g.:
import requests
from numba import jit, objmode


@jit()
def x():
    with objmode(t="unicode_type"):
        t = requests.get("https://google.com").text
    print(t[:15])


x()

Prints:
<!doctype html>

